# How can I redefine the style of the \lstlistoflistings title?

Tags: listings, titles, renewcommand

I am using a cls based on `memoir` and the package `listings`.
I want an appendix chapter with all the lists (list of tables, list of figures, list of listings). The title style of these lists should be like a `section` title.

I can do this for the tables and the figures like this:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@lofmaketitle{%
  \section*{\listfigurename}%
  \tocmark%
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@lotmaketitle{%
  \section*{\listtablename}%
  \tocmark%
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

So I figured it should also work for the listings but the following has no effect:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@lolmaketitle{%
  \section*{\lstlistlistingname}%
  \tocmark%
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

I use `\lstlistoflistings*` so I wouldn't want it to show up in the TOC.

How can I do this?

Comment: LOF, TOF and TOC are genereated by memoir and follows its rules, LOL is not a part of memoir thus follows its own rules. Please make a full example using memoir with a listing example and a list of listings in an appendix. Then we have something to work with,

Comment: Having said that listings actually use `\tableofcontents` and locally redefine what `\contentsname` points to and which file to use.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Hest]
a
\end{lstlisting}


\begingroup

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocmaketitle{%
  \section*{\contentsname}%
  \markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother

% adding a star to \lstlistoflistings does not work, the inner 
% \tableofcontents never sees it. Locally use \KeepFromToc 
% to emulate the *
\KeepFromToc
\lstlistoflistings
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Note that the change cannot really be in preamble as it also affects `\tableofcontents`.

The relevant code from `listings` is

```
\lst@UserCommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
    \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
    \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
    \tableofcontents \egroup}
```

here we can see it resets `\contentsname`, and what file `\@starttoc` should use. `\tableofcontents` usually executes `\@starttoc` so they jsut executes `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: This now lets me use redefine the list title and displays the heading of the list as section. That solves this exactly as I wanted. But the asterisk I use to not display the section in the TOC (`\lstlistoflistings*`) has no effect anymore.

Comment: Again `\lstlistoflistings` is not a `memoir` command thus does not support the `*` I listed the code and you can see that `\tableofcontents` has an `\egroup` after it so it never sees the `*`. You can do something else, see the update.

Comment: This does it, thanks a lot. To be honest I never really changed much on default layouts and am still finding my way around the LaTeX syntax.

Comment: As for `\lstlsitoflistings` one could not know this without looking at the code.